# SSH Tunnel into Aurora DB via the CLI

Tags: ssh, amazon-aurora, ssh-tunnel

Is there a simple **step by step** example on how to SSH into a private Aurora MySQL db?

something like:

```
mysql -h dbDomain.pair.com -u dbUser -p dbName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for how to config RDS to be remote accessible, if that's the case, check this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-private-public-endpoints/

For me I wouldn't make my db access via public endpoints, instead, I would setup as private and only can access from my VPC LAN.

Then I use a EC2 instance as proxy, and access the database via LAN ip from SSH tunnel.

To do that, you need check the VPC document, setup subnets etc.

AWS document is a good place to start.

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/vpc/latest/userguide/what-is-amazon-vpc.html

Update: if you already set the db to be private, take a look at this
https://linuxize.com/post/mysql-ssh-tunnel/

Comment: I should have added the db is not public but private, I'll update that in my question as well

Comment: @KristiLuna, then take a look at this https://linuxize.com/post/mysql-ssh-tunnel/